# make_bucket failed: s3://my-first-bucket Unable to locate credentials

Tags: aws

Estoy intentando entrar en las practicas de localstack para poder simular la plataforma de aws y poder practicar los servicios de forma local, cuando voy por el paso de crear un ***Bucket*** siguiendo el comando:
***$ aws s3 mb s3://my-first-bucket --endpoint-url=http://localhost:4566***

***Me genera el mensaje:***
make_bucket failed: s3://my-first-bucket Unable to locate credentials.

Pero lo cierto es que si hice mis credenciales son las siguiente:

nebulosa@LAPTOP-LA9SFT99:~/.aws$ cat credentials

[localstack-nebulosa]

aws_access_key_id = 1234

aws_secret_access_key = 1234

nebulosa@LAPTOP-LA9SFT99:~/.aws$ cat config

Como soluciono este problema?. Para seguir avanzando en localstack en las practicas de aws.

[profile localstack-nebulosa]

region = us-west-2

output = json

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: Credenciales]

Answer (score 0):

Las credenciales no están asociadas al perfil por defecto sino a `localstack-nebulosa`. Tienes que añadir el perfil a la petición:

```
aws s3 mb s3://my-first-bucket --endpoint-url=http://localhost:4566 --profile localstack-nebulosa
                                                                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```